# How to provide array with nested array for GET request in Laravel in Swagger api doc

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I use

```
 "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.0",
```

and in storage/api-docs/api-docs.json located in first line

```
"openapi": "3.0.0",
```

in my controller in get request

```
 *   @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="request_body",
 *     in="query",
 *     description="all request data which needed",
 *     required=false,
 *     @OA\Schema(
 *          ref="#/components/schemas/EstateListRequest"
 * )
```

EstateListRequest model has props_ids

```
/**
 *
 * @OA\Property(
 *      type="array",
 *          @OA\Items(
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                    property="discriminator",
 *                    type="string",
 *                    example="discriminator"
 *               ),
 *              @OA\Property(
 *                      property="ids",
 *                      type="array",
 *                      @OA\Items(type="integer"),
 *                      description="array of configure_property_id ids"
 *              )
 *          ),
 *      description="array of discriminators with configure_property_id array"
 * )
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $props_ids;
```

in storage/api-docs/api-docs.json I faced with that

```
                "props_ids": {
                    "description": "array of discriminators with configure_property_id array",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "discriminator": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "example": "discriminator"
                            },
                            "ids": {
                                "description": "array of configure_property_id ids",
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
```

and in UI everything looks correct, but when I filled data like needed I faced with that
[image]

I faced with the in GET, it's was not array on objects

```
array (
  'props_ids' => 
  array (
    'discriminator' => 'world',
    'ids' => '3',
  ),
)
```

Url in swagger looks like that

```
http://dev.local.com/api/v1/estates?props_ids[discriminator]=hello&props_ids[ids]=4&props_ids[ids]=5&props_ids[ids]=6&props_ids[discriminator]=world&props_ids[ids]=1&props_ids[ids]=2&props_ids[ids]=3
```

I expected something like that

```
http://dev.local.com/api/v1/estates?props_ids[0][discriminator]=hello&props_ids[0][ids][0]=4&props_ids[0][ids][1]=5&props_ids[0][ids][2]=6&props_ids[1][discriminator]=world&props_ids[1][ids][0]=1&props_ids[1][ids][1]=2&props_ids[1][ids][2]=3
```

and in GET var like that

```
$propd_ids = [
   [
      'discriminator' => 'hello',
      'ids' => [4, 5, 6],
   ],
   [
      'discriminator' => 'world',
      'ids' => [1, 2, 3],
   ]
];
```

so, what I'm doing wrong ? How it should be ?

Answer (score 0):

I used a swager some time ago, I had the same problem and could not find a solution.
Finally I used type string or json (I can't remember). I submit the data in it from the frontend as json.

This is not the best solution, but it works for me.